# Updating the scope through directive. Best practices

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am struggling with the concept of scope while working with a directive. I read through the [offical](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope) [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element) as well as half a dozen blogs and stuff, but i am not able to get this done.

I have 5 fields for text input. What i want to achive is, if one field is filled, the next sibling shall appear:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="entry in activeField.entries">
        <td entry-value contenteditable="">{{entry.value_0}}</td>
        <td entry-value contenteditable="" ng-show="entry.value_0">{{entry.value_1}}</td>
        <td entry-value contenteditable="" ng-show="entry.value_1">{{entry.value_2}}</td>
        <td entry-value contenteditable="" ng-show="entry.value_2">{{entry.value_3}}</td>
        <td entry-value contenteditable="" ng-show="entry.value_3">{{entry.value_4}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is my directive `entryValue`

```
terminal.directive('entryValue',function(){
return{
    restrict: 'A',
    controller: 'terminalController',
    link: function(scope, element){

        element.bind('input',function(){              
            // Here i want to update the scope
        })
    }
  }
});
```

As the user makes an input, i want to push that value to my controllers scope, which contains the object activeField. I have tried to bind $watch to my directives linking function as well as `scope.$apply()` but neither works.

I'd appreciate any help

Comment: kindly show complete code or set up  a plunker demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<tr ng-repeat="entry in activeField.entries">
    <td entry-value contenteditable="" 
     ng-hide="!$first && !activeField.entries[$index-1].value">{{entry.value}}</td>
</tr>
```

```
app.directive('entryValue',function(){
return{
    replace: true,
    controller: 'terminalController',
    template: '<div><input ng-model="entry.value"></div>',
    link: function(scope, element){
    }
  }
});
```

```
$scope.activeField = {entries: 
  [ {value: ''}, {value: ''}, {value: ''}, {value: ''}, {value: ''} ] };
```

<kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/BxfkY/)</kbd>